# Mem leaks even in cases where you dont Alloc or init

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Instruments reports that I get a memory leak in the 2 lines of code at the use substringWithRange. I don't have any alloc,copy or inits explicitly used with this code so I dont understand why this happens.

The memory leaks only appear when they viewController that this code is related to closes.

Here is the offending code:

```
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"radio" ofType:@"txt"  
    inDirectory:@""];
NSString* data = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding: 
    NSUTF8StringEncoding error: NULL];      
NSString *nString;

NSString *nHolder;
NSString *iHolder;
NSMutableArray *sHolder = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]autorelease];

for (int i=0; i<data.length; i++) 
{
    nString = [data substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)];
    if ([nString isEqualToString: comma])
    {
        if (commaCount == 0)
        {
                             // LEAK Reported from the below line
            nHolder = [data substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i-rangeCount, 
                            rangeCount)];
        }
        else if (commaCount == 1)
        {
                            // LEAK Reported from the below line
            iHolder = [data substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i-rangeCount, 
                            rangeCount)];
        }
            }
    pInfo  *myInfo = [[[pInfo alloc] init] autorelease];
myInfo = nHolder;
myInfo = iHolder;
  }
```

And pInfo

```
@interface pInfo : NSObject 
{
NSString *name;
NSString *info;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *info;

-(id)init;
@end
```

In the dealloc method of pInfo I dont release anything since I have no allocs.

I would appreciate it if somebody could enlighten me to what I do wrong here.

The stack trace is

-[NSCFString substringWithRange:]
CFStringCreateWithSubstring
__CFStringCreateImmutableFunnel3
_CFRuntimeCreateInstance

Thanks
-Code

Comment: what is data and nString and where did they come from?

Comment: added that in. Also commented the exact lines of the reported leaks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instruments is telling you where the leak was allocated, not where it was actually leaked!

You will be looking for a retain that is not balanced by a release.  In the Allocations instrument, you can turn on retain count tracking and then look at all the retain/release events and see which retain isn't balanced or is otherwise incorrect.

What do you do with nHolder and iHolder?

Comment: Added the code you requested. There is retain in the pInfo class. But I've never know that require a release when there is no associated alloc.

Comment: If you retain it, you must release it.  Since the @property is causing the retain, you need to release the two ivars in dealloc.  Note that since pInfo (btw:  all class names should start with a capital letter) is not leaked, that nails the problem to being a missing release in that class...

Comment: hmm ok i will add 2 releases for those vars in the dealloc method of pInfo class. Or would a better soloution be to remove the retain?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where the leak is coming from (too little data).

It looks like you are trying to find the first and second comma in `data` and then pull out a part of `data`.

If so just use the string parsing/searching API something like

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/rangeOfString:options:range:locale:

where the `string` in the first argument is `@","` and the `range` is 0 to end for the first pass, the second pass the `range` to search would be where the first comma was found to the end.

After you find the two ranges you are looking for then you can use `substringWithRange:` to get the interesting string.